# ActionScript 3's error output #1034 Type coercion failed

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, type-coercion

I want to create a character's controls. Unfortunately, I have encounter an error #1304.

Here's the output error :

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert class_Boy$ to 
flash.display.MovieClip.
    at class_Boy/mainJump()
    at class_Boy/class_Boy_Move()
```

The flash can run but when I pressed Space bar, the error keeps repeating and the flash stopped.

I believe that the culprit is caused by `MovieClip(boy_Class)` under the class_Boy's class. Please help me if you can find any solution. Thanks.

This is the main class :

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.*;

public class experimentingMain extends MovieClip 
{
    var count:Number = 0;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10,count);

    var classBoy:class_Boy;

    var leftKey, rightKey, spaceKey, stopAnimation:Boolean;

    public function experimentingMain() 
    {
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, scoreUp);
        myTimer.start();

        classBoy = new class_Boy();
        addChild(classBoy);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressTheDamnKey);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, liftTheDamnKey);
    }

    public function pressTheDamnKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 37)
        {
            leftKey = true;
            stopAnimation = false;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 39)
        {
            rightKey = true;
            stopAnimation = false;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 32)
        {
            spaceKey = true;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }
    }

    public function liftTheDamnKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 37)
        {
            leftKey = false;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 39)
        {
            rightKey = false;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 32)
        {
            spaceKey = false;
            stopAnimation = true;
        }
    }

    public function scoreUp(event:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        scoreSystem.text = String("Score : "+myTimer.currentCount);
    }

  }
}
```

This is the class of class_Boy :

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class class_Boy extends MovieClip
{
    var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
    var mainSpeed:Number = 5;
    var mainJumping:Boolean = false;
    var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 40;
    var jumpSpeed:Number = 0;

    var theCharacter:MovieClip;

    var currentX, currentY:int;

    public function class_Boy()
    {
        this.x = 600;
        this.y = 500;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, class_Boy_Move);
    }

    public function class_Boy_Move(event:Event):void 
    {
        currentX = this.x;

        if (MovieClip(parent).leftKey)
        {
            currentX += mainSpeed;

        }

        if (MovieClip(parent).rightKey)
        {
            currentX -= mainSpeed;
        }

        if (MovieClip(parent).spaceKey)
        {
            mainJump();
        }

        this.x = currentX;
        this.y = currentY;
    }

    public function mainJump():void
    {
        currentY = this.y;

        if(!mainJumping)
        {
            mainJumping = true;
            jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit*-1;
            currentY += jumpSpeed;
        } else {
            if(jumpSpeed < 0){
                jumpSpeed *= 1 - jumpSpeedLimit/250;
            if(jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit/12){
                jumpSpeed *= -2;
                }
            }
        }
        if(jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit)
        {
            jumpSpeed *= 1 + jumpSpeedLimit/120;
        }
        currentY += jumpSpeed;
        if(currentY >= stage.stageHeight - MovieClip(class_Boy).height)
        {
            mainJumping = false;
            currentY = stage.stageHeight - MovieClip(class_Boy).height;
        }
      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast it to MovieClip. You can just use `this` since this is that instance of the class_Boy class you have in your parent class. Also, `class_Boy` is the name of your class so casting it to anything just does not make sense.

Comment: No problem. You might also want to adapt proper naming conventions as the user below suggested to avoid confusions - although it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `MovieClip(class_Boy)`, it should have been simply `this`, which is the object that refers to the current instance running the code. `class_Boy` is the class itself, used to instantiate new objects.

This kind of problem is prevented when using the common coding standard of naming variables and methods starting with lowercase (`parent`) and classes with uppercase (`Sprite`). Then when you see `MovieClip(ClassBoy)` it's clear there's an error because `ClassBoy` is a type of class.

A couple other things that may also help you:

- if you follow the standard of starting class names with uppercase, you don't start it with `class`, and you can just name it `Boy`
- methods don't have to start with the class name (`class_Boy_Move`). In fact it's better if they don't, so you don't confuse with the constructor and they end up shorter